# DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged. I am trying to change button colour

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game. I found some code, but it doesn't work well. When you click on the button then it should change the button color and text. The problem is when I click

1. writes to discord "The application does not respond"
2. work fine
3. throw an Error

I am using discord.js 14
If you have a better code then send it here, this is the only one which I found.

Code:

```js
 if (interaction.isButton()) {
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();
    collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
        //loop through each action row on the embed and update it accordingly
        let newActionRowEmbeds = i.message.components.map((oldActionRow) => {
            //create a new action row to add the new data
            const updatedActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder();

            // Loop through old action row components (which are buttons in this case)
            updatedActionRow.addComponents(
                oldActionRow.components.map((buttonComponent) => {
                    //create a new button from the old button, to change it if necessary
                    const newButton = ButtonBuilder.from(buttonComponent);

                    //if this was the button that was clicked, this is the one to change!
                    if (i.component.customId == buttonComponent.customId) {
                        //If the button was a primary button then change to secondary, or vise versa
                        if (buttonComponent.style == ButtonStyle.Primary) {
                            newButton.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);
                            newButton.setLabel("X");
                        }
                    }
                    return newButton;
                })
            );
            return updatedActionRow;
        });
         // and then finally update the message
        await i.update({components: newActionRowEmbeds});
    });
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\vojta\tictactoe\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:667
        throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\vojta\tictactoe\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:667:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\vojta\tictactoe\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:464:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\vojta\tictactoe\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:910:22)
    at async ButtonInteraction.update (C:\Users\vojta\tictactoe\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:233:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/vojta/tictactoe/src/index.js:115:3) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 7,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: [ { type: 1, components: [Array] } ],
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1049732802192617552/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTA0OTczMjgwMjE5MjYxNzU1Mjp5d1FqWGh4bU82eVh1eVBrRWJsZnhWS2FibjZqSWNRMWhaSWN2YlZ1YU5nVHZsdEw2VUxZWGEzb0JQcHJQaUFPQVkyeHJ1NGp0WXZNUlE1all2YmkyQlA2ZHlpRUQ2ZUhDSUFUeVNWYkREaVc4OFdLWmVoMlpZUXJnQ1M5eWdyQw/callback'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: now it stop throwing errors but doesn't work

Comment: why don't you use a module, go and check it out in npmjs, there are many tictactoe modules for djs v14

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice about npmjs I didn't know until now